Не получается отправить видео в группу
from pyrogram import Client, filters
from hachoir.metadata import extractMetadata
from hachoir.parser import createParser
from datetime import datetime

import cfg


def progress(current, total):
    print(f"{current * 100 / total:.1f}% : {datetime.now().strftime('%d_%H:%M:%S')}")

api_id = cfg.api_id
api_hash = cfg.api_hash






def test(path):
    app = Client('account', api_id, api_hash)
    metadata = extractMetadata(createParser(path))
    duration = (0, metadata.get('duration').seconds)[metadata.has('duration')]
    width = (0, metadata.get('width'))[metadata.has('width')]
    height = (0, metadata.get('height'))[metadata.has('height')]
    with app:
        app.send_video(cfg.chat_id, path, progress=progress, duration=duration, width=width, height=height)

Пытаюсь отправить видео размером 200мб в группу через другой файл вызывая функцию test(). Видео не отправляется. В чём может быть проблема незнаю, надеюсь на вашу помощь. Использую aiogram со стороны исполнения функции.

Что в консоле? Откуда берется файл? Ограничения соблюдены?
